# Using Custom Font

Tags: java, fonts, awt

I am trying to set font of a JLabel to a custom font. No exceptions are thrown reading the file, but nothing appears when I call `label.setText("string")`. Text appears when I comment out the line `label.setFont(f)`. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? This code is inside a JPanel class.

```
    _mineLabel = new JLabel();

    _timeLabel = new JLabel();

    try {
        Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,new File("/Users/simon/Documents/workspace/Minesweeper/bin/minesweeper/DS-DIGI.TTF"));
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(f);
        f.deriveFont(12f);
        _mineLabel.setFont(f);
        _timeLabel.setFont(f);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.add(_mineLabel);
    this.add(_timeLabel);
    _timeLabel.setText("test");
```

Comment: try `f= f.deriveFont(12f)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
    f.deriveFont(12f);
```

to

```
 f=f.deriveFont(12f);
```